# Как в Django создать атрибут модели без добавления поля в БД?

Tags: python, django

У меня определена модель Article в models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=256)
    short_content = RichTextField(config_name='awesome_ckeditor')
    full_content = RichTextField(config_name='awesome_ckeditor')
    cover = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='uploaded_images')
    cropping = ImageRatioField('cover', '200x200')
    show = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    visits = models.BooleanField(default=0)
```

Команда **makemigrations** сгенерит мне sql для создания таблицы в БД с соотв. полями.
Как мне сделать, чтобы, атрибут **cropping** в модели был (нужно для создания миниатюр изображений в админке), но при этом отдельное поле в БД для него не создавалось?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте @property
Вот так например:

```
@property
 def full_name(self):
     "Returns the person's full name."
     return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

В Вашем случаи:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=256)
    short_content = RichTextField(config_name='awesome_ckeditor')
    full_content = RichTextField(config_name='awesome_ckeditor')
    cover = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='uploaded_images')
    show = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    visits = models.BooleanField(default=0)

    @property
    def cropping(self):
        "Returns cropped image."
        return <--Код который будет кропить и возвращать картинку -->
```

Обратите внимание що поле **сroping** мы убрали с модели. В базе его не будет, но при запросах будет доступно. Такое себе виртуальное поле.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант посмотрите в сторону ProxyModels: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#proxy-models

Или unmanaged models: можно создать такую же модель как оригинальная, но она не будет трекаться в миграциях.

Это будет полезно если надо именно поле модели которое надо провалидировать, а не просто property. В основном применяется для read cases. Для save придется немного поиграться: например из прокси создать рельный инстанс и сохранить его.